# PIR motion sensor stuck in a loop

Tags: sensors, teensy

I've bought an HC-SR501-compliant **PIR motion sensor** (like [this one](https://learn.adafruit.com/pir-passive-infrared-proximity-motion-sensor/)) and connected it to a **Teensy 3.1**. The circuit seems fine, and the LED lights up. However, **when nothing is moving in front of it, the sensor keeps reporting HIGH and LOW in suspiciously constant intervals**. The monitor reads like this (numbers in milliseconds)

```
motion detected  4113
motion stopped   7234
motion detected  4114
motion stopped   7274
motion detected  4113
motion stopped   7204
motion detected  4111
motion stopped   7184
```

When it detects movement, it stays on the triggered position for longer, but even then goes back to predetermined intervals, e.g.

```
motion detected   4113
motion stopped   17204
motion detected   4111
motion stopped   41754
motion detected   4113
```

This is the sketch ([as found on Adafruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/pir-passive-infrared-proximity-motion-sensor/using-a-pir)):

```
int ledPin   = 13;              // choose the pin for the LED
int inputPin = 1;               // choose the input pin (for PIR sensor)
int pirState = LOW;             // we start, assuming no motion detected
int val      = 0;               // variable for reading the pin status

unsigned long lastTime = millis();

void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);      // declare LED as output
  pinMode(inputPin, INPUT);     // declare sensor as input

  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  unsigned long currentTime = millis();

  val = digitalRead(inputPin);   // read input value
  if (val == HIGH) {             // check if the input is HIGH
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);  // turn LED ON
    if (pirState == LOW) {  

      // we have just turned on
      Serial.print("motion detected ");
      Serial.println(currentTime - lastTime);

      // We only want to print on the output change, not state
      pirState = HIGH;

      // Save time for measurement
      lastTime = currentTime;
    }
  } else {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW); // turn LED OFF
    if (pirState == HIGH){

      // we have just turned off
      Serial.print("motion stopped ");
      Serial.println(currentTime - lastTime);

      // We only want to print on the output change, not state
      pirState = LOW;

      // Save time for measurement
      lastTime = currentTime;
    }
  }
}
```

**Could this be a faulty device?** I'm thinking about getting a new one for testing. While I can compensate for the gaps when triggered, I can't think of a way to make sure that it's not actually being triggered by this weird internal interval.

Answer (score 1):

Try powering the PIR motion sensor with a higher voltage.  I get the same problem you're seeing when powering it with the 3.3v output of an Adafruit Huzzah ESP-12, but it works just fine when I power it with the 5v USB power.

Comment: From the Adafruit page:  "Runs on 5V-12V power (if you need to run it off of 3V you can do that by bypassing the regulator, but that means doing a bit of soldering)."  So powering it from the Teensy's 3.3V may be the problem.